# Format time value as HH:MM:SS

Tags: sql-server-2008, time

How I may be able to Trim down Time DataType when retrieving from the database?

```
Value from the Database : 08:00:00.0000000
What I need : 08:00:00 only
```

I'm SQL Server 2008, VB.Net 2010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not really trimming (that's removing leading or trailing spaces), but any of these should work in SQL:

```
SELECT CAST(@YourValue as time(0))
```

or

```
SELECT LEFT(@YourValue, 8)
```

or

```
SELECT CAST(@YourValue as char(8))
```